# Registrar entrada y salida de un personal

Tags: django

Estoy creando una aplicación que me permita registrar la entrada y salida diaria de un personal en una tabla o formulario.

Pero estoy bloqueado, ¿Como se debería hacer?
Este es mi modelo, el cual me permite registrar la entrada y salida de una persona mediante  una clave foránea.

**model.py**

```
class RegistrarAsistencia(models.Model):
codper = models.ForeignKey('cuenta.Persona', on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_column='codper_id', verbose_name='Personal')
entrada = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
salida = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.entrada, self.salida)      

class Meta:
    ordering = ['codper']
    db_table = 'asistencia\".\"registrar_asistencia'
    unique_together = (('codper'),)
```

A continuación el form:
**forms.py**

```
class RegistrarAsistenciaForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = RegistrarAsistencia

        fields = [
            'codper',
        ]
        labels = {
            'codper': 'Codigo personal'
        }

        widgets = {
            'codper': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
        }
```

La vista:    **views.py**

```
class ListarAsistencia(ListView):
    template_name = 'controlasistencia_listar.html'
    extra_context = {'titulo':'Control de asistencia',
                    'sub_titulo':'Asistencia OPSU-CNU'}
    context_object_name = 'controlasistencia'


class PersonalAutoComplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Persona.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            queryset = Persona.objects.get(cedper=self.q)

        return queryset
```

### esta vista se deberia cambia a clase ###

```
def formulario_asistencia(request, id=None):  

    contexto = {}
    if id is None:
        contexto['form'] = RegistrarAsistenciaForm()
    else:
        contexto['id_asistencia'] = RegistrarAsistencia.objects.get(pk=id)
        contexto['form'] = RegistrarAsistenciaForm(instance=contexto['id_asistencia'])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if id is None:
            contexto['form'] = RegistrarAsistenciaForm(request.POST)
        else:
            contexto['form'] = RegistrarAsistenciaForm(
                request.POST, instance=contexto['id_asistencia'])
        if contexto['form'].is_valid():
            with transaction.atomic():
                if id == None:
                    contexto['form'].save(commit=False)
                    contexto['form'].save()
                    print("se guardo correctamente")
                else:
                    contexto['form'].save(commit=False)
                    contexto['form'].salida = timezone.now()
                    contexto['form'].save()

                    print("se edito correctamente")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('controlasistencia:listar-asistencia'))
    return render(request, "asistencia_formulario.html", contexto)
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'controlasistencia'

urlpatterns = [
    path('personal', PersonalAutoComplete.as_view(), name='personal'),

    path(  # Listar
        'controlasistencia/',
    ListarAsistencia.as_view(
        model=RegistrarAsistencia,
        template_name='asistencia_listar.html',
        extra_context={'titulo': 'Control de asistencia', 'listado': 'Personal'},

    ),
    name='listar-asistencia'),

    path(
        'controlasistencia/agregar', formulario_asistencia, name="agregar-asistencia"

    ),
    path(
        'controlasistencia/editar/<int:id>', formulario_asistencia, name="editar-asistencia"

    )
]
```

El problema esta en que cuando registro una persona solo me registra la entrada y si cambio de día no lo hace. 
¿Como puedo hacer para que me valide la entrada y si registro a la misma persona el mismo día me registe la salida.

Gracias por toda la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Answer (score 0):

Debes validar en tu vista si ya existe un registro con el `codper` que están enviando por el formulario y la fecha actual, si es así entonces lo que debes hacer es guardarle la fecha actual al registro encontrado, de lo contrario guardas los valores del formulario normalmente. tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera. (puedes agregarle mas validaciones claro esta)

```
def formulario_asistencia(request):
    form = RegistrarAsistenciaForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrarAsistenciaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            codper = form.cleaned_data['codper']
            date = datetime.now()
            register = models.RegistrarAsistencia.objects.filter(codper=codper, entrada=date)
            if register != None:
                register.salida = datetime.now()
                register.save()
            else:   
                form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('controlasistencia:listar-asistencia'))
    return render(request, "asistencia_formulario.html", contexto)
```

Espero te sirva, saludos

Comment: Gracias, pero no me sirve me sigue dando el error por lo pronto seguire tratando de ver si puedo crear una clase createview y una update view para que me permita registrar tanto la entrada como la salida diaria, si se te ocurre algo mas, de nuevo gracias

Comment: Cual es el error que te sale? puedes agregar el traceback?

Comment: No me muestra ningun error en pantalla, cuando reviso la base de datos, me muestr el registro, pero cuando voy a realizar otra entrada esta no me la registra a menos que elimine el que ya existe, incluso probe con otros codigo pero no me deja registrar nada mas.